# htaccess redirect exception fails and can't figure why...?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

From our client's site (http://www.cfm33.com/) we need to redirect all mobile devices to the mobile site (http://m.cfm33.com/), and this works.

But we really need an exception for the reservation page, so that users even on mobile get redirected to this reservation page of the desktop site.

Here's what's in the .htaccess :

```
## Mobile redirect
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone|Android|iPad|iPod|Blackberry
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif|\.svg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !reservation-formation.html [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://m.cfm33.com/ [R]
## End mobile redirect
```

Any idea why the exception does not work ? We've been trying for a few hours and still no clue...

Any idea ? Could this have something to do with some custom routing on the desktop site ?

Thanks

David

Comment: Not sure if it's pertinent, but try escaping the `.` in `.html` (`\.html`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
## Mobile redirect
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone|Android|iPad|iPod|Blackberry
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/reservation-formation\.html [NC]
RewriteRule !\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$  http://m.cfm33.com/ [R]
## End mobile redirect
```

Replaced `REQUEST_URI` by `THE_REQUEST` as other rules might be affecting `REQUEST_URI` whereas `THE_REQUEST` remains unchanged.